# WordPress rewrite rule for RSS feed

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have just moved a blog from Squarespace to self-hosted WordPress and am trying to set up a rewrite rule so that the old RSS links will continue to work for existing subscribers.

The URLs I am working with are as follow:

Squarespace: http://example.com/blog/atom.xml
WordPress: http://example.com/feed/

I sed the following code in my functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'ss_feed' );
function ss_feed()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( 'blog/atom\.xml$', 'feed/' );
}
```

This has successfully caused my .htaccess file to be updated:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/atom\.xml$ /feed/ [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

However hitting http://example.com/blog/atom.xml still results in a WordPress 404. Can anyone shed any light on what might be the issue here? Note that I have WP Super Cache enabled and it has a large block inside the .htaccess as well, I can add here if folks think that might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your permalinks within the Wordpress admin as a first troubleshooting step. That often fixes such issues.